# How can I cause editing of EditText to happen in full screen mode?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

As shown in the landscape images here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html .

I don't necessarily need to do the fullscreen thing, but my issue is that the EditText is below the soft keyboard and I cant figure out how to get the whole thing to display above it. Its a note field, and fills whatever open space there is from the end of my other fields to the bottom of the screen. Currently when I select the note, the screen moves up just enough to see the top of the note field, but this is not good enough. I want the top of the note field to move up to the top of the screen, to maximize what the user sees while they are editing the field.

My softInputMode in the manifest is adjustPan, but changing these settings has not done anything for me.

Comment: I have not yet picked a best answer because there hasn't been a post that answers the question, nor have I solved it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a ScrollView around the view to make it slide and change adjustPan to adjustResize (adjustPan is normally not recommended) to the activity on the manifest.

Comment: This almost works, however it allows the edit text for the note field to grow infinitely large. I do not want this, I just want it to take up the remaining space on the screen as in the screenshot. However, wrapping my linear layout in a scroll view causes the note to take on the height of however many lines of text the note contains.

Comment: Can't you define a maxHeight in dp ?

Comment: I am staying away from defining maximum heights, because as I see it, there will always be a larger and smaller version of what is already out there.